# ¿Cómo puedo desencriptar una cadena cifrada en JS y descifrarla en Java?

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

He generado el codigo de encriptación en JS de esta forma:

```
   function generateHash(textValue) {
  const secretKey = generateRandomKey();
  const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(textValue, secretKey).toString();
  return encrypted;
}
```

Esa función de cifrado se la paso a un QR para poderlo generar con ese hash; he desarrollado una aplicacion en android studio con java para que escanee el QR generado y de ahi obtenga el hash, de igual manera el usuario tiene que insertar la clave secreta generada en la app para poder descifrar el mensaje.

El detalle es que no hace la desencriptacion, trae correctamente el valor del QR con su respectivo hash y la clave secreta tambien pero no desencripta.

Necesito ayuda por favor!

Este es el codigo de android studio:

```
package com.example.mobile_hash;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import android.util.Base64;

public class Decrypt extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txv;
    private EditText inputKey;
    private String encryptedHash;
    private String decryptedHash;
    private String secretKey;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_decrypt);

        txv = findViewById(R.id.message);
        inputKey = findViewById(R.id.in_Key);

        // Obtener el hash encriptado del intent
        encryptedHash = getIntent().getStringExtra("encryptedHash");

        Button decryptButton = findViewById(R.id.decrypt_Btn);
        decryptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Obtener la clave secreta ingresada por el usuario
                secretKey = inputKey.getText().toString();

                // Desencriptar el hash
                decryptedHash = decryptHash();

                // Mostrar el hash desencriptado en el TextView
                txv.setText(decryptedHash);
            }
        });
    }

    private String decryptHash() {
        try {
            // Configurar el cifrado con el algoritmo y modo adecuados
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

            // Inicializar el cifrado en modo de descifrado con la clave secreta
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);

            // Decodificar el hash encriptado de Base64
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedHash, Base64.DEFAULT);

            // Desencriptar el hash
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
            String decryptedHash = new String(decryptedBytes);

            return decryptedHash;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mi codigo para generar mis claves secretas

```
function generateRandomKey() {
  const randomBytes = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(8);
  return randomBytes.toString();
}
```